# "Run-time error 13: Type Mismatch" when creating chart in excel vba

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I want to create a chart in excel vba. At the top of a class module, I declare myChart 
with this line:

```
private myChart as chart
```

Then, in a subroutine within that class module, I set myChart to a new chart using this line:

```
set myChart = ActiveWorkbook.charts.add
```

At the set statement, i get this error:

"Run-time error 13: Type Mismatch"

It's frustrating because this error sometimes doesn't happen, and further, I'm able to make charts using the same statement in different class module.

---EDIT---

My class module (named SandChart) is below. I trimmed it down for everyone's sake,
but of course the error still persists:

```
Option Explicit

Private myChart as Chart
Private chartname as String


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
chartname= "Sand Trends"
End Sub


Private Sub makeCoarseChart()
DisableScreenUpdates
eliminateOld
initChart
EnableScreenUpdates
End Sub


Private sub eliminateOld()
Dim chrt as chart
For Each chrt in charts
    if chrt.name = chartname then
        Application.DisplayAlerts=False
        chrt.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts=True
        Exit For
    End if
Next chrt
End Sub


Private Sub initChart()
Set myChart= ActiveWorkbook.charts.add
mychart.name= chartname
mychart.ChartType=xlAreaStacked
End Sub
```

In my main module, i have the following line which is the starting 
point of my macro:

```
new SandTrends.makeCoarseChart
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Also I feel, you do not understand how variable declarations work. `myChart` is a variant in that subroutine. I would recommend you read more about variable declaration.

Comment: Is there a reason I'm not supposed to declare a chart object in a class module? Are class modules only reserved for declaring certain data types? If so, that would be strange. Then again VBA is strange...

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  According the locals window, myChart is of type Chart when this error occurs. So I don't believe it is a variant as you say you do.

Comment: In order to really diagnose this, we need to see more of your code. The quesiton remains: why are you declaring myChart in a class module? Some additional information about *what* you're trying to do, and *why* you think this is the best way to do it, may help shed some light on the problem.

Comment: IOW, it's not that you *can't* or *shouldn't* declare this in a class module, but we dont' understand *why* you think you need to do this. (perhaps you do, but that is not clear).

Comment: Where is your sub routine declared? In a normal module or somewhere else? If it is a normal module then Locals will not show it as a Chart Type unless you have re-declared the variable in that module or the sub routine. It will show as a Variant since you have declared the variable in the class module. Dim/Private are the same. You might want to see [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: @DavidZemens. THe class in question is for building a certain type of chart. Each chart I create has it's own class. I'm trying to create one of these charts, and that's where the error comes (but just for this class). I prefer to focus on the error, not the style.

Comment: @SiddharthRout. I just posted code. To answer your question, the routine is in the class at question. THanks for your help.

Comment: I believe this to be a bug. Excel VBA sometimes doesn't act up when I comment things out then uncomment them (and other oddities)...